# Grim Dawn: Skeletons causing meteor shower

Tags: grim-dawn

I am playing Grim Dawn with all the DLC except Loyalist items packs.
My character is a Shaman Necromancer (level 32) and I have no item granting meteor shower skill and no active constellation with that skill.

I noticed that when I summon my skeletons (Necro skill level 12) for a while they can use the meteor shower skill (after a while sometimes they stop doing it). I am sure of that because if I do not summon the skeletons I do not see the meteors.
It started when my skeletons appeared "equipped" with armor, when they were lower level they appeared "naked" and the meteors did not happen.

In the skeleton skills popup I do not see any reference to that skill, just the usual damages and other stats.

I do not understand if it is a bug or I am missing something in the skill system.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After rank nine of your [Raise Skeletons skill](https://grimdawn.gamepedia.com/Raise_Skeletons_(Skill)) you have a chance to summon a skeletal arcanist who uses spells (including meteor showers).

Unfortunately I don't know about a direct way to see the tooltip about the meteor shower per-se but in [Grimtools](https://www.grimtools.com/calc/a2E34MPZ) you can press <kbd>tab</kbd> on the skill to cycle through the stats of the different skeletons you can summon.

Comment: GrimTools is a wonderful site, but I cannot make that TAB trick. I open the skill page, i point to raise Skeleton. In the popup I see that with TAB some stats change, but I do not see the arcanist. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Luca maybe it's a bug in Grimtools. If you lower the Rank to 9 it's easier to find them by their spawn weight (10%) which is displayed in the tooltip. Or by comparing the spawn weight to the Table in the [article I've linked](https://grimdawn.gamepedia.com/Raise_Skeletons_(Skill)).

Comment: in GrimTools I see the stats of skeletons changing at each TAB press, and they match the excellent article you linked. That article does not mention meteors, but probably I understood. They are Arcanist, the arcanist class has the Inferno skill that produces lightning and meteors. (I also have lightning from my gear). So probably it is not a meteor shower, it is the effect of an arcaninst skill.